# Trigger 2-second animation on :active...impossible?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a css animation that I want to trigger on :active using purely css.

```css
#myShape:active {
  animation: glow 2s;
}

@keyframes glow {
  from { box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #f00; }
  to { box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #fff; }
}
```

This works, as long as the mouse is held down. But...

if you let go of the mouse before the animation is over, it stops immediately. The duration doesn't last beyond the time the mouse is clicked! It stops on mouse-up.

What parameter am I missing? How do I force the animation sequence to finish after the active state is over? I can't believe this is impossible with CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **CSS transition** property to add animation.

```css
/* I did without animation (@keyframes)*/
#myShape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #9a9999;
  transition : box-shadow 2s;
  
  }

#myShape:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #f00;
  transition-duration : 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="myShape"><div>
```

Comment: Not bad! Still doesn't work the way I want, though, since it stays on while the mouse is down. I'll have to find a javascript implementation after all. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```css
@keyframes glow {
  from,to { box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #f00; }
  50%{ box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #fff; }
}
```

```css
#myShape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  }

#myShape:active {
  animation: linear infinite 2s glow;
}

@keyframes glow {
  from,to { box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #f00; }
   50%{ box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #fff; }
}
```

```html
<div id="myShape"><div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It only animates while the mouse is being held down. This also animates forever, which is not what I want. I need a solution that will run the entire 2-second animation even after the mouse is done clicking.